# How to install AWS Redshift ODBC driver to Alpine in Docker. (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-redshift

I am creating a database connection to AWS Redshift using ODBC for Node.js. It is easy to install into Windows using the following link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html

But as I am trying to execute the application using Docker container I have to install is to Node:Alpine.

What are the ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alpine does not support the C/C++ library version required by the driver. If you can live with slim, here's how to install:

```
FROM node:lts-slim
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install wget -y \
    && wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/odbc/1.4.45.1000/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.45.1000-1.x86_64.deb -qO /tmp/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.45.1000-1.x86_64.deb \
    && apt-get install /tmp/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.45.1000-1.x86_64.deb \
    && rm /tmp/AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.45.1000-1.x86_64.deb
```